# How to setup Tomcat server in Netbeans?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I googled a bit and found that it can be done by *services--->servers--->add new*, 
but when I try to add new Tomcat server this way, it doesn't appear in the list. Actually nothing is displayed to select from. What can I do now? I have successfully configured Tomcat for Eclipse.

Comment: @madth NB--->6.1 tomcat-->6.0.35

Answer (score 18):

In Netbeans 8 you may have to install the Tomcat plugin manually.
After you download and extract Tomcat follow these steps:

1. Tools -> Plugins -> Available plugins, search for 'tomcat' and install the one named "Java EE Base plugin".
2. Restart Netbeans
3. On the project view (default left side of the screen), go to services, right click on Servers and then "Add Server"
4. Select Apache Tomcat, enter username and password and config the rest and finish

Answer (score 11):

I had same issue. No need to re install.

In Netbeans 6.0 , Find RunTime -> Servers - > Add server -> select Tomcat install 'root' directory

In Netbeans 7.x -> Tools -> Servers-> Add server -> select Tomcat install 'root' directory

Here is in Netbeans Wiki.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/AddExternalTomcat

Comment: In Netbeans 8 you may have to first install the Java EE Base plugin

Answer (score 3):

While installing Netbeans itself, you will get an option which servers needs to be installed and integrated with Netbeans. First screen itself will show.

Another option is to reinstall Netbeans by closing all the open projects.

Comment: Agreed, this is the easiest way. I only wanted to mention that the install file has to be the Java EE bundle or the full bundle.

Comment: I reinstalled as u said. and its true that it shws us to select servers we want to run @ run time..there tomcat was already selected.then I tried to add a new server as usual. but there is nothing in the list..(except Webrick which is built in for Ruby)...@madth3:::it was full bundle...plz help me..

Comment: @AchiniSamuditha,

[link](http://qa.netbeans.org/modules/webapps/promo-f/tomcat/tomcatint.html) will guide to your target...

I followed that link, Integrated Netbeans 7.0 with Apache tomcat 7.0.25.... 


Cheers, Happy Integrating...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the mentioned answers, I repeatedly got this error `The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid.` Mine is a Windows system.

It’s rather simple to sort this.

Go to `File Explorer` and locate your Tomcat Folder.
(The path for mine was `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0`)

Open the Tomcat Folder (`Tomcat 9.0`).

You will most likely get a message saying you have no permission (or something to that effect). Click the button which gives you Permanent Permission.

Now close File Explorer, and paste the path (`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0`) in the required field in NetBeans and continue installation. That’s all!!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If TomCat is install. Perhaps it is not installed Java EE. Services-> plug-ins-> additional plug-ins-> in the search dial tomcat. and install the module java ee. then in the services, servers, add the tomcat server.