# Java Web app failed to start on Tomcat 9 with Netbeans 11 on Mac OSX Sierra

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I have an issue with Netbeans 11 and Tomcat 9 on Mac OSX Sierra (10.11.2)

I've a Java Web Application (non-maven project) and I'm not able to deploy the WAR into the running Tomcat.

After several minutes an error is raised in console:

```
/build-impl.xml:1092: Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed.
```

I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8

I've searched for this kind of issue and found other people struggling with the same error so I've tried the suggested solutions but nothing have worked

I've changed the config in order to have "No proxy" setting
I've also tried with Tomcat 8 and Tomcat 7 but same error occurs.
I've added the server attribute to the Tomcat connector as metioned here: [Starting of Tomcat failed from Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225764/starting-of-tomcat-failed-from-netbeans%3E)

but nothing works.
For the sake of completeness I say that the Tomcat starts correctly because respond on localhost:8080 (I can see the admin page).

I've also copied the WAR into the webapps folder and file was correctly uncompressed and the Web application, in this way, is correctly running.

It's seems that Netbeans is not aware of Tomcat start so deploy is not performed.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: I guess you have problem with starting tomcat server in netbeans. checking this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/27642357/4431053

Comment: @Spara, based on his question, I'm fairly certain that tomcat is installed properly. I have the same problem. Have you had any luck figuring this one out?