# The specified Server Location Catalina Home folder is not valid. NetBeans 8.2 , Apache Tomcat/7.0.105

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I have Apache Tomcat installed in the address

/usr/local/apache-7/apache-tomcat-7.0.105

Environment variables point to that address

$CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/apache-7/apache-tomcat-7.0.105

$CATALINA_BASE=/usr/local/apache-7/apache-tomcat-7.0.105

The problem comes when from netbeans 8.2 I try to add a tomcat server that gives the error: The specified Server Location Catalina Home folder is not valid. In netbeans the address that I add is the one of the variable $ CATALINA_HOME

Where is the problem?

thanks all.

Comment: Hi Dani, wellcome to SO, please read this thread and try in the future to search first in google. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131764/how-to-setup-tomcat-server-in-netbeans/27642357